# Run aws cli looping over names from a text file - parameter store

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, sh

I'm trying to run an awscli command for multiple resources as a loop in a bash script.

For example:

```
aws ssm get-parameters --name "NAME1", "NAME2", "NAME3"
```

I've added all the parameter names into a text file. How do I run the CLI command against each name in the file?

Here is my script:

```
AWS_PARAM="aws ssm get-parameters --name" $FILE
FILE="parameters.txt"

for list in $FILE; do
 $AWS_PARAM $list
done
```

The expected output should run the CLI on all the names in the file.
I know the CLI is expecting the "name" of the parameter store. I'm hoping someone can help with looping the names from the list and running the CLI.

Thank you!

Comment: Read the file [line by line](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/) in a shell script and call the awscli one time for the name on each line.

Comment: @jarmod - thanks for the hint. I'm trying to output the results into a file, but my code only shows results for one entry.

AWS_PARAM="aws ssm  get-parameters --with-decryption --names"
file="parameters.txt"
while IFS= read line
do
    # display $line or do something with $line
    $AWS_PARAM "$line" > out-parameters.txt
done <"$file"

Comment: # display $line or do something with $line
    $AWS_PARAM > out-parameters.txt "$line" 
    
done <"$file"

Comment: You use `> output.log` to truncate the output file then write to it. You use `>> output.log` to append to it. I recommend that you `echo > output.log` and then simply `>> output.log` each time you call awscli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to iterate over the parameter names and log the output to one file:

```
#!/bin/bash

AWS_PARAM="aws ssm get-parameters --name"
input="input.txt"
output="output.log"

echo > "$output"

while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
  $AWS_PARAM "$line" >> "$output"
done < "$input"
```